# Issues when creating using oracle_fdw extension in windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, oracle-fdw

I'm trying to install and use oracle_fdw in postgresql 9.6, however I keep receiving the same issue every time that I run the following command:

```
create extension oracle_fdw;
ERROR:  could not load library "D:/PostgreSQL/pg96/../pg96/lib/postgresql/oracle_fdw.dll": 
    The specified module could not be found.
```

Two things are very strange here:

1. the folder that it's looking for the dll, has a ".." in the middle, so it seems it should look into `D:\PostgreSQL\pg96\lib` only, but I do have the folder `D:\PostgreSQL\pg96\lib\postgresql` as well.
2. I set the following variables in the system, but it seems not to reflect in the command:

   ```
   Path: D:\PostgreSQL\pg96\lib\;C:\Program Files\Oracle Instant Client\instantclient_12_2; 
       D:\PostgreSQL\pg96\lib\postgresql
   ```

Are you guys able to help me? I really need specific instructions on how to make it work.

Tks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with the Postgres distribution you are using rather than oracle_fdw itself. It might be a better idea to reach out to the distribution packagers.
Looking at the paths in your errors I am assuming you are using the Bigsql distribution. You can try posting the question on their feedback page, they are generally quite responsive.

Answer (score 0):

The `..` in your path is strange, but should not be a problem. What is the value of the parameter `dynamic_library_path`?

Is `oracle_fdw.dll` in `D:/PostgreSQL/pg96/lib/postgresql`?

I assume that `oci.dll` is in `C:\Program Files\Oracle Instant Client\instantclient_12_2`.
Did you check that all programs involved (PostgreSQL, oracle_fdw and Oracle) are either all 32-bit or 64-bit?

If all that is ok, the problem must be that `oci.dll` is not on the shared library search path of the PostgreSQL server.

Are you sure that the PostgreSQL service has got the `PATH` setting you show? Did you restart PostgreSQL after you changed the `PATH` environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Many are running into this issue and I got it resoved in most cases.
Oracle Client libraries are compiled using specific version of Visual C++. So we need to have Visual C++ redistributable package of that particular version of Visual Studio is required in the system.
Second dependancy is coming from `oracle_fdw.dll`. Lastest community version of `oracle_fdw.dll` is prepared using Visual C++ 2013. So we need to have Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable package to be present in the system.
Once all such dependanices are solved, it works.

Alaternatively, you can use `oracle_fdw.dll` prepared by BigSQL project. Since the project is built using MSYS2, there is no dependancies to Visual C++. However the dependancy created by Oracle client libraries cannot be avoided.